# What is Rogue's normal "uniform"?

Tags: marvel, comics, rogue, uncanny-avengers

In the Uncanny Avengers' promotional "shot" (see below), Rogue is shown dressed very much like Quicksilver, to the point where I confused the two.  Is this Rogue's normal outfit, or is this something new for Uncanny Avengers?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not really new. That outfit is a variation on her original outfit she wore when she first met the Avengers as a member of the Brotherhood of Evil Mutants.

[image]

She has worn some variation of it for a number of years even after she started working with the X-men. Most of her costumes were a variation of her first one with a green and yellow, or green and white variation. Her costumes have almost always been fully covering to protect others from her powers.

Her most recent one resembles her very first one. Compare the newest with the first above:

[image: Modern Rogue, Alex Garner]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform); it is a [costume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costume).  Note that all six have different costumes.  There is no Avengers uniform.

What may be confusing you is that we have normally seen Rogue in the X-Men uniform.  For whatever reason, she is not wearing her X-Men uniform while in the Avengers (the obvious reason being that she is currently in the Avengers, not the X-Men).  A typical [X-Men uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rogue2CoverByMikeWieringo.jpg.gif):

[image: Rogue in X-Men uniform]

Interestingly, that picture is from her solo comic **Rogue** but still has her in X-uniform.

[X-Men uniforms on Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Uniforms).

As already stated in the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20210/30870), the Avengers costume is a return to her original costume style prior to joining the X-Men.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(comics)) notes that she also wore a Ms. Marvel costume for a while.